# Change input form when checkbox is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

I would like to create a webform which gives users the opportunity to create tickets more easily.

In this webform I have two input forms and a checkbox:
[image: Screenshot]

What I would like to have is the following (created via PowerPoint):
[image: Screenshot]

So if the users click the checkbox the webform should automatically disable the second input form and copy the value and/or the placeholder of the first input form. So briefly speaking: If the users click the checkbox the second input form should be exactly like the first one, except that it is disabled.

Unfortunately I have no clue how to do this. By now my code looks like this:

Input field 1 (key user) + checkbox:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="keyuser">Key-User:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10"> 
  <input type="keyuser" class="form-control" id="keyuser" placeholder="Username Key-User">

  <div class="checkbox">
    <label onclick="checkbox()">
        <input type="checkbox">
    </label>Is the affected user
  </div>
</div>
```

Input field 2 (affected user):

```
  <div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="affuser">Affected User:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10"> 
  <input type="affuser" class="form-control" id="affuser" placeholder="Username affected user">
</div>
```

Checkbox() [it does not work at all right now]:

```
function checkbox() {
"use strict";
if (check === "False") {
    check = "True";
    $('#affuser').attr('placeholder', 'Username Key-User');

} else {
    check = "False";
    $('#affuser').attr('placeholder', 'Username affected user');
}
```

}

How can I implement the functions mentioned above?

Comment: Shouldn't your check be a boolean value instead of a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some changes that I would want to implement to your script rightaway:

- Do not use inline JS. Instead, create an `onchange` event handler for the checkbox (not the label element)
- Use IDs for your checkbox so that your `<label>` will be functioanlly attached to it.

For the JS, it's quite simple: When an `onchange` event is registered on the checkbox element, evaluate if it is checked or not, by simply evaluating the `.is(':checked')` boolean:

- If checked:

  - disable the `#affuser` element using `.prop('disabled', true)`
  - update the placeholder attribute using `.attr('placeholder', ...)`
- If unchecked:

  - enable the aforementioned element using `.prop('disabled', false)`
  - update the placeholder attribute using, again, `.attr('placeholder', ...)`

```js
$(function() {
  $('#checkbox1').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#affuser')
        .prop('disabled', true)
        .attr('placeholder', $('#keyuser').attr('placeholder'));
    } else {
      $('#affuser')
        .prop('disabled', false)
        .attr('placeholder', 'Username affected user');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="keyuser">Key-User:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="keyuser" class="form-control" id="keyuser" placeholder="Username Key-User">

    <div class="checkbox">
      <label for="checkbox1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
    </label>Is the affected user
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="affuser">Affected User:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="affuser" class="form-control" id="affuser" placeholder="Username affected user">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The disabling function works perfectly fine now, but how could I implement the function so that the value/placeholder of "keyuser" is automatically copied to "affuser" when the checkbox is clicked?

Comment: @TimKühn If you want that, simply read the placeholder attribute value of the keyuser input and assign it, i.e. `$('#affuser').attr('placeholder', $('#keyuser').attr('placeholder'))`. I have updated the answer to reflect this ;)